# omniauth-facebook and fb_graph not working together

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth, fb-graph

I am developing a rails 3.2 application and am authenticating using omniauth-facebook.  This part has been giving me no problems.  I get the `request.env['omniauth.hash']` successfully and I extract the Oauth token as such.

```
auth_hash = request.env['omniauth.hash']
token = auth_hash['credentials']['token']
```

Afterwards I try to hit Facebook's Open Graph using fb_graph as such:

```
user = FbGraph::User.me(token)
```

However when I do this, my user is not loaded.  I just get a blank user and it seems like facebook is not accepting my token as a valid token for some reason.  Am I doing something wrong?  Is the token I have not the one I need to make Facebook Open Graph requests?  Help is much appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried making a curl request using the token you get back?  What's the response from that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try user = FbGraph::User.me(token).fetch